# pygame window disappearing immediately after it has been oppened

Tags: loops, pygame, window

I have a problem with a pygame window disappearing immediately after it has been opened I know this can be resolved with a loop around the pygame.quit but i cant be able to solve it.

```
    enter code he      enter codeimport sys
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    quit = 1
    if(quit == 2):
        pygame.quit
    if (quit == 1):
        wind = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
        width = 300
        height = 300
        x = 300
        y = 300
        vel = 1re
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You window closes immediately, because your application is immediately terminated. You need an application loop. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

e.g.:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(100)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (250, 250), 100)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it quits because the code has finished executing, and I don't see a loop in your code currently...

Maybe something like:

```
# Initialise your pygame stuff

isRunning = true

while isRunning:
    # Respond to events from pygame
    if certainCondition: 
        isRunning = false

pygame.quit()
```